# Can't upload unmanaged package

Tags: apex, package, unmanaged-package

I created unmanaged package and when upload it I receive the following error: "Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class PageMessageComponentController Method does not exist or incorrect signature: {method_from_existed_class}". Class PageMessageComponentController is not exist (deleted long time ago). I checked and can't find it in developer console

Answer (score 2):

This error is telling you that you have a class that called a method from the PageMessageComponentController class. As an educated guess, I would say that you wrote another class that provides unit tests for this class, and you forgot to delete that class as well. Use the Developer Console in Salesforce to search for PageMessageComponentController (Edit > Search in Files), and you should find the code you need to modify/delete.

Answer (score 0):

Do you parent package for this one? because I think otherwise you wouldn't able to create a version with errors.
So you need to first install the parent package and this one

Answer (score 0):

I pressed "Compile all classes" and find some errors in test classes. And after resolving I was able to upload the package.

However, I have no idea why it shows me an error in deleted class